# The indexPath of custom table cell is undefined, objective c

Tags: objective-c, custom-cell, didselectrowatindexpath

I have created a custom cell call PendingDoctorTableViewCell and is used in PendingDoctorTableView. Everything is work find and i added a disclosure indicator by using

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
```

It's able to performed the segue "ShowPendingDoctor".

However when i used the prepareForSegue, the indexPath is undefined.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {



    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowPendingDoctor"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ActionForPendingDoctorViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.myObjects = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
        //   destViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
}
```

How can i get to know which row had been tap. because its always return the object of 1st index.

Anyone can help me? i'm rushing for my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable of NSIndexPath to save your currently selected indexPath

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

Use Tableview delegate to identify selected row and perform segue programmatically

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER sender:self];
 }
```

Pass your object to next ViewController through prepareForSegue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER]) 
   {
      ActionForPendingDoctorViewController *destViewController =    segue.destinationViewController;
      destViewController.myObjects = [myObject objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
   }
 }
```

Comment: I added a line selectedIndexPath = indexPath; in the tableVIew didSelectRowAt IndexPath with your code and now its work !! Really thanks a lot! Thank you. Your help is highly appreciate!